# Looking for Aerial Photography Flight Planning plugin

Tags: software-recommendations, aerial-photography

Where I can find a plugin called A M Flight Planner?

Comment: Plugin for QGIS?

Comment: Plugin into which GIS software are you trying to use ?

Answer (score 2):

Quick Google search has this: http://www.airbornescientific.com/content/osacplanning

But your question doesn't have enough information to work out if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I found the same page through Google but was unable to find this particular plugin available anywhere. I am looking to create flight plans for aerial survey imagery and what to use either QGIS or Arc